# How to have multiple NOT LIKE in SQL

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I have two tables in a database. `Contacts` and `Filter`

In `Contacts`, I have `ID`, `Name`, and `Email` as the fields.

in `Filter`, I have `ID` and `code`

My objective is to be able to query the entire table and export a list that has been filtered by items in the Filter table. (basically the same that could be achieved with a  grep -i -Ev ) ... Basically I want to filter out gmail or yahoo or others).

So if I do

```
select distinct email from contacts where email not like '%gmail%'
```

One level of the filter works. 
but if I do,

```
select distinct email from contacts where email not like '%gmail%' or not like '%yahoo%'
```

then things start to fail.

Before I start to integrate the nested select code in filter, I cannot get the multiple where field not like X or field1 not like Y working.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

**sample data**

```
name           email 
bob            bob@gmail.com
joey           joey@cisco.com
```

**desired output**

```
joey@cisco.com
```

UPDATE: Thank you all for your help. Answer to phase I of the question was to change from OR to AND.  :)

Phase II: Instead of having a query that is larger and larger,.. I would rather use a query determine the items to exclude (meaning if any of them match, then exclude them).. so I would then add yahoo gmail protonmail to records in the code field of the filters table.. with that would it be

```
select distinct email from contacts where email not like in (select code from filters)
```

This fails as it says that the select has multiple records

UPDATE:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email FROM Contacts WHERE email NOT LIKE (select filters.code from filters where filters.id=4)
```

works.. but is only pulling one record as the filter. not all of them as filters.

Comment: `AND` instead of `OR`.

Comment: You are missing your field name after the or, you need to specific a field for each "not like" -   select distinct email from contacts where email not like '%gmail%' or email not like '%yahoo%'

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use AND instead of OR.

```
SELECT distinct email 
FROM 
    contacts 
WHERE 
    email not like '%gmail%' 
    AND email not like '%yahoo%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can benefit from `CHARINDEX` like below, I think this will increase the performance of your query. Also, you can use `group by` instead of `distinct`, it will also help the performance.

```
select email 
from contacts 
where charindex('gmail',email) < 1 
  and charindex('yahoo',email) < 1
group by email
```

Answer (score 0):

If your select has two NOT LIKE criteria connected by an OR condition then everything will meet the criteria.  In this situation "gmail" is not like "yahoo" and "yahoo" is not like "gmail" so even those two will pass the criteria.  By converting the select to use the AND condition instead you capture those situations.  The syntax requires you to provide the field name in both conditions.  I feel that this code is easy to read and meets your needs.

```
SELECT distinct email 
FROM contacts 
WHERE email not like '%gmail%' 
   AND email not like '%yahoo%'
```

Comment: A valid point.  I felt that the context had already been addressed in previous answers.  I was merely providing my version of Gordon's code.

Comment: revised the commentary to explain my reasoning

Answer (score 0):

Two issue

you need   the column name for each condition  so add email after the OR

```
 select distinct email from contacts where email not like '%gmail%' or email not like '%yahoo%'
```

and could be you want check for bot in the same time so  you need AND

```
 select distinct email from contacts where email not like '%gmail%' AND email not like '%yahoo%'
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the correct boolean connector with `NOT LIKE` is `AND`, not `OR`.

You might see the logic using `NOT`:

```
select distinct email
from contacts
where not (email like '%gmail%' or email like '%yahoo%');
```